# Batch: How to make a .txt file with all files in a folder without extensions

Tags: file, list, batch-file, file-extension, filelist

right now i have this code:

```
@echo off

dir Maps /A-D /b /o:gne >Maplist.txt

start notepad Maplist.txt
```

But i makes Maplist.txt like this:

a.bsp

b.bsp

c.bsp

but i want it without ".bsp"

please help

Comment: have you looked into the FORFILES loop? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on the FOR command - type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command window to see the documentation.

The following code will do exactly what you want.

```
@echo off
>Maplist.txt (
  for %%F in (Maps\*) do @echo %%~nF
)
start notepad Maplist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Has speech marks annoyingly, I'm assuming you don't want those either? (It does get rid of extension though)

```
forfiles /p files /c "cmd /c echo @FNAME >> maplist.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks but yes it would be great if it only was the name and nothing else but again thanks for taking time :D